# Button not databinding to model correctly

Tags: c#, ado.net

I having problems with a button I created that is supposed to databind to a gridview. It should search authors by last name, but when I click the button nothing happens. Can anyone help me with my code?

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="BookForm.aspx.cs" Inherits="BookWebApp.BookForm" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        Enter Author&#39;s Last Name:
        <asp:TextBox ID="lastNameBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="applyButton" runat="server" OnClick="applyButton_Click" Text="Apply" />

    </div>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="ISBN" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ISBN" HeaderText="ISBN" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ISBN" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Title1" HeaderText="Title1" SortExpression="Title1" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="EditionNumber" HeaderText="EditionNumber" SortExpression="EditionNumber" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Copyright" HeaderText="Copyright" SortExpression="Copyright" />
            </Columns>
            <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:EntityDataSource ID="bookEntity" runat="server" ConnectionString="name=BooksEntities" DefaultContainerName="BooksEntities" EnableFlattening="False" EntitySetName="Titles">
        </asp:EntityDataSource>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is the `findButton_Click` (I assume that's what we're talking about) event getting called at all? Does a breakpoint get hit?

Comment: Actually it's the applyButton_Click. Ignore findButton_Click. And the breakpoint does get hit because I set it and when I click the apply button, it jumps from the web app to the code, but I don't see any errors?

Answer (score 0):

First, you should change your `Page_Load` to

```
if(!Page.IsPostBack)
{
    // load Authors table ordered by LastName then FirstName
    dbcontext.Authors
       .OrderBy(author => author.LastName)
       .ThenBy(author => author.FirstName)
       .Load();

    // specify DataSource for authorBindingSource
    authorBind.DataSource = dbcontext.Authors.Local;
}
```

When the button is clicked, you don't want to reload all that data. It can also cause some unexpected behaviors.

Then, does it help at all if you call `DataBind` on your `GridView`? Admittedly I'm not seeing where the `GridView` is being assigned to the `BindingSource`, but I'm trusting that that's working.

Comment: I updated the code above and added what you said. Also I assigned GridView to the BindingSource inside PageLoad, but it still doesn't work. Did I not assign the gridview correctly? Or is it something else?

Comment: You want it the way it's commented out. You should be setting `GridView1.DataSource = authorBind`. Does the GridView ever show anything? From your question I got the impression that it was only when the button was clicked that any problems arose.

Comment: If it never shows anything--and I'm not immediately familiar with `BindingSource`s since I usually do custom stuff so this stems from that--add in `GridView1.DataBind()` any time you change `authorBind`.

Comment: I updated the code again. This time I commented out the other line of code and uncommented  GridView1.DataSource = authorBind; But if I run the code this way I get this error. http://postimg.org/image/oqt1mezlt/full/

Comment: Is your `BindingSource` defined in your design code? If so, you shouldn't be creating a second one here.

Comment: I don't think so. I didn't see BindingSource in the toolbox in design mode. So I added it programmatically with this line of code.  BindingSource authorBind = new BindingSource();

Comment: According to that error code, you're setting the `DataSourceID` property of `GridView1`. Given that isn't happening in your C# here, I'm inclined to assume it's happening in your ASPX file. Am I right on that? And if so, try removing that attribute and trying it again. If you aren't sure what I mean, could you post the code that defines `GridView1` to your question?

Comment: The error is happening in my ASPX file. I defined Gridview with the gridview option in toolbox. So I didn't define that programmatically. It was just the BindingSource and BindingNavigator I defined in the aspx.cs file. Then I assigned GridView1 as such: GridView1.DataSource = authorBind; So I am a little confused on what you want me to post?

Comment: I'm looking for the actual design source code. I'm not sure if all versions of VS show this the same way, but I believe at the bottom left of your designer screen there should be three buttons: Design, Split, and Source. If you click the Source button, that will bring you to some HTML-esque code that has somewhere on it "<asp:GridView" then some attributes. I'm looking for everything between where it says "<asp:GridView" and the first following ">".

Comment: Oh ok. I updated the code above for the design mode source code

Comment: Awesome, perfect. See in `<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="ISBN" DataSourceID="bookEntity" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">` where it says `DataSourceID="bookEntity"`? Try deleting that attribute.

Comment: I updated the code again above. When I remove that attribute the gridview disappears and all I see is the textbox and apply button, but no gridview

Comment: Huh. The plot thickens. You added in the `GridView1.DataBind()` line, right?

Comment: Do you mean  GridView1.DataSource = authorBind;? The aspx.cs file looks like this currently http://pastebin.com/y1vhYv9A

Comment: No, just before the closing brace of the `if (!Page.IsPostBack)...` that I had you add, put in the line `GridView1.DataBind();`.

Comment: By doing that I'm getting an InvalidOperationException. UPDATED: http://pastebin.com/9CNBXPLD

Comment: Okay, maybe that isn't what you're supposed to do with `BindingSource`s. That's possible, again I never use them. In fact, try getting rid of that `BindingSource`. Just set `GridView1.DataSource = dbcontext.Authors.Local` directly.

Comment: I changed it, but now I get the error Both DataSource and DataSourceID are defined on 'GridView1'.  Remove one definition. UPDATED: http://pastebin.com/JHe9VDJN

Comment: Okay, try the same fix for that as before--remove the DataSourceID. Then we'll address why it's getting added back in.

Comment: I had to leave for work. I'll be back and post an update at 11:30pm est

Answer (score 0):

See if the button is asp button or simple html buttons. And also check if it has runat=Server tag enclosed with it.